# could not rectify segmentation fault in multithreaded application on Centos6.7 64-bit machine

Tags: c, linux, debugging, centos, segmentation-fault

My multi-threaded application is causing segmentation fault on one machine. But It is running successfully on another machine with same set of data input. To track this problem I compiled my app with -g and without stripping it ran on problematic machine. And debugged same version of my app with generated core dump. But I am not getting any useful information to find the problematic line. Below is the result of debugging my app with core dump file.

[image]

Even I also compiled myapp and ran it under gdb on problematic machine.Then also I did not get useful information. Below is the output of the same.
[image]

Kindly let me know how can I trace segmentation fault over here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part of your code is corrupting memory, possibly in the very memcpy that is on the stack -- but due to the corruption you have wacked all the trace information.   Try to run it with valgrind or a similar memory anaysis tool (and no, it does not work correctly on the other machine either, but some memory difference hides the error for a later day)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg -- does the post not say he already did compile with -g?